# Use crontab job to modify global environment variables

Tags: shell, cron

This question has boring me a whole day...

I want to modify root's environment variables $bai automatically, and I write a shell script and add it to root's crontab. but $bai is not changed.

here is my script /root/111.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=`date`
export bai=$time
```

here is the crontab:

```
*/1 * * * *  . /root/111.sh
```

Then `echo $bai` is null

but when I `source /root/111.sh` and `echo $bai`, it can get the time: `Wed Dec 24 17:02:48 CST 2014`

So how can I get the environment variables by use it in my cron job?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change variables in a different process like that. Probably the nearest you can do is to use a file, something like this.

In `crontab`:

```
* * * * * /bin/date > /tmp/value.txt
```

In some other script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do 
   v=$(cat /tmp/value.txt)
   echo $v
   sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suppose you do is to modify exported variables. But there's no way to a child process to modify environment of a parent process. The only way to set variables is from parent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are in 2 different bash. The crontab issues the command and export the variable `$bai` to the current session that just opened and then exits, and with it the initialized `$bai`, that's why when you do it locally by issuing `source /root/111.sh` you see that the `$bai` is created, because you are creating the variable in your bash session.

If you want to have the `$bai` variable every time you open a bash session, you need to add it in `.bashrc` file that is in your home directory by adding

```
echo "export bai=\`date\`" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Every time you start a bash if you issue `echo $bai`, you'll get the date... BUT if you want the `$bai` variable being updated every x time, then this approach is not correct as it will keep the date when you logged in, and crontab is not going to help you because of my first explanation.